# C++ not catching exception, causing python to terminate

Tags: python, c++, exception, boost-python

I have a function that throws an exception, and I want to handle it in C++:

```
#include <boost/python.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void yay( ) {
  cout << "thowing exception" << endl;
  try {
    throw;
  }catch(...) {
    cout << "Exception caught" << endl;
  }
}


BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(libyay){
  using namespace boost::python;
  def("yay", yay);
}
```

I am creating python bindings using boost.python. When I call the function yay() in python, I'd expect the exception to be caught and execution to continue normally. Here is my python test script:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
sys.path.append('./build')
import libyay

libyay.yay()
```

However, instead, I get the following output

```
thowing exception
terminate called without an active exception
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Anyone know what's going on? My understanding was that since the exception is being caught in c++, it should be transparent to the python interpreter.

Comment: You are using `throw` in C++ without specifying the actual exception. That syntax is for rethrowing exceptions (inside `catch` blocks.) I don't know what it does elsewhere. Change it to something else, e.g. `throw 1;`.

Comment: @yzt What is that comment for? That is already explained in the dupe, without bogus advice like throw integers.

Comment: @BaummitAugen: Thank you for marking the dupe, but my comment predates your mark. Therefore, I'd say the comment is suggesting something to try to the OP. Throwing integers, whether bogus or not, is nonetheless fits right into the category of "things to try" to find the problem and then going about solving it.

Now *this* comment is pretty useless. But I couldn't stop myself from replying to yours.